# Browse to a specific S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

Wondering how to view this S3 bucket in the normal AWS S3 console?  If I browse to the link below, all I get is an xml list of contents.  I want to view the bucket in the normal AWS console so I can download particular files from the bucket.

http://hadoopbook.s3.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to view an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket URL directly in the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) for the following two reasons:

- First and foremost, you need to be the owner of the bucket, because *the AWS Management Console provides convenient management of **your** compute, storage, and other cloud resources [emphasis mine]*; that is, you must be logged into your account to gain access to the resources associated with that particular account, there is no way to gain access to other account's resources.
- Even if this would be your bucket, it is still not possible, insofar the AWS Management Console is a [Rich Internet Application (RIA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application), which makes extensive use of JavaScript to achieve its functionality, thus doesn't offer URL addressable resources/views for most of its functionality (unfortunately). This is not a RIA restriction as such and could be relaxed or remedied in principle (e.g. some parts of the console offer query parameters like `region` already), but is usually not a high priority either for RIAs either and to the best of my knowledge not available right now.

So if it is your bucket indeed, you'll need to browse to it via the AWS Management Console yourself.